# Creating a 32-bit object file from C file

Tags: c, assembly, linker

I have a library that basically implements a print and I have an object file in 32-bits and I want to create an object file with the print library and link them together.  The problem is whenever I try to create a 32-bit.
Am I missing something?

I've tried compiling using `gcc -m32 -o print.o print.c` and now tried `gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o print.o -c print.c` but if i remove the `-m32` flag it works but it generates a 64 bit file

but for some reason I get this error:

```
In file included from print.c:2:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PRINT(int num)
{
    printf("%d\n",num);
}
```

Comment: On the face of it, your compiler (or, more accurately, the supporting libraries and headers) are not installed correctly.  If you omit the `-m32`, do you get a different result?

Comment: This sometimes happens when you don't have the 32bit headers installed.

Comment: yeah i needed to do sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib and it works now, thanks a lot

Comment: Apart from missing gcc-multilib, `-ffreestanding` seems unlikely to work with `stdio.h` and its functions.  Also, `gcc -m32 -o print.o print.c` is missing a `-c`, so you're actually linking an executable called `print.o`.